# Routing in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

Here is a picture of board:

[image]

I want to route pad 23 to 48. But the path gap is narrow. So I am not able to route it. Auto routing also couldn't route. I changed the design rules for solder mask and track width as much as possible.

How can I achieve the routing?

Comment: Can you give more information on the package you are using, and/or the grid scale?

Comment: @Camil Staps I am using 0.025mm grid

Comment: A link to the part you are dealing with would help.

Answer (score 4):

There is no magic bullet here.  You either use smaller trace/space widths, route it a different way, or you don't route it at all.

Comment: Using a smaller annular ring on the inner layers than the outer layer could help give more clearance.

Answer (score 2):

Can you place a Via close to the Pad and then go on a lower layer? You might also want to look at typical fanouts: http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/Fanout+and+Escape+Routes

Addition: You might want to plug that via to prevent tin from being sucked into the hole